# Is $n^{\frac{1}{n}}$ is always greater than equal to $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Show that $n^{\frac{1}{n}} \ge 1$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am taking elementary course in analysis. So I am trying to prove it using simple arguments.
Suppose it is not. Then $n^{\frac{1}{n}} < 1$. Now, $n^{\frac{1}{n}} $ being the rational power of positive real is always greater than $0$. Now, we can use following result

if $0<x<y$ then $x^n<y^n$ for any natural $n$.

So $n^{\frac{1}{n}} < 1$ will give us that for any fixed $n_0$,  $n_0<1$. This will hold for all such $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. It is a contradiction

Comment: I would change the ending a bit to make your argument clearer: "In particular this means that $n=(n^{\frac{1}{n}})^{n}<1^{n}=1$, which is a contradiction." Otherwise the argumentation is sound.

Comment: Thank you Floris. It is much more neat now...

Comment: Do you know arithmetic-geometric means inequality?

Comment: If we are allowed to use the monotony of $n^x$, we need not a proof via contradiction, we simply have for every $n\ge 2$ : $1/n>0\implies n^{1/n}>n^0=1$

Comment: Yes. I know about the AM-GM inequality. And, yes that also leads the answer

Comment: @K.Chandra Using this inequality seems for me to be like shooting with rockets on ants, but that is probably a matter of taste. If you know this inequality, you probably also know logarithms, which lead to an easy solution as well as $\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$ is obviously positive for $n>1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $n^{1/n}=1-\epsilon$, for some $\epsilon\in(0,1)$, then [Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says
$$
\begin{align}
n
&=(1-\epsilon)^n\\[6pt]
&=\frac1{\left(1+\frac\epsilon{1-\epsilon}\right)^n}\\[-3pt]
&\le\frac1{1+\frac{n\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}}\\[6pt]
&\lt1
\end{align}
$$
By contradiction, we must have $n^{1/n}\ge1$.

---

Furthermore, Bernoulli's Inequality also says
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^{2n}
&\ge\left(1+\sqrt{n}\right)^2\\
&\gt n
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
1\le n^{1/n}\lt\left(1+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2
$$

Comment: Using the [Binomial Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem), we can get better: at least $n^{1/n}\lt1+\sqrt{\frac2n}$, but this is not significantly better than what is given above.